# Continuous surjection from plane to closed unit interval such that preimage of each point is bounded

Tags: general-topology

Preparing to an exam I will have next year I came across the following problem. Unfortunately, I have no ideas, so all hints are welcome.

Does there exist a continuous surjection $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to [0, 1]$ such that the full preimage $f^{-1}(x)$ of every $x \in [0,1]$ is bounded? Can such a function be monotonous (i. e. such that the full preimage of every compact is compact)?

Comment: Normally, a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ is called *monotone* if $f^{-1}(y)$ is **connected** for every $y\in Y$

Comment: You might want to keep in mind our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [avoiding "I have no ideas" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 4):

Will this do it? (Here I'm regarding $\mathbb R^2$ as $\mathbb C$ for ease of notation.)

$$f(z) = \left(\frac{2}{1+|z|} - 1\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1 - |z|}{1+|z|}\right)^2$$

**Addendum:**

- $z\mapsto 1 +|z|$ sends $\mathbb C$ onto $[1,\infty)$
- $z\mapsto \dfrac2z$ sends $[1,\infty)$ onto $(0,2]$
- $z\mapsto (z-1)^2$ sends $(0,2]$ onto $[0,1]$

Composing these maps gives $f$.

**Addendum 2:**

Here we use the notation $C_R\equiv\{z\in\mathbb C : |z| = R \}$.

- The set $f^{-1}(0) = C_1$ is compact
- The set $f^{-1}(1) = C_0$ is compact
- For $0<r<1$, the set $f^{-1}(r) = C_s \cup C_{1/s}$ is compact, where $s = \dfrac{1-\sqrt r}{1+\sqrt{r}}$

Answer (score 1):

Using the complex plane as $\mathbb R^2$, identifying $(x,y)$ with $x+iy = z$:

First map $z \mapsto |z|^2$, so the image is $[0, \infty)$.

Now map $[0, \infty)$ homeomorphically to $[0, \pi)$ by $x \mapsto 2 \arctan(x)$.

Map $[0, \pi)$ to a half-open semicircle via $x \mapsto \exp(ix)$.

Finally take each point of this semicircle to its $y$-coordinate.

The composition of these maps satisfies the requested conditions:

$f(x,y) = \sin(2 \arctan(x^2 + y^2))$

Comment: It appears that this problem would be considerably harder or impossible to solve if we added the condition that the inverse image of each x ∈ [0, 1] must be *connected*.

Comment: I used some [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to clean up the math formulas.

Comment: Thanks, Lee Mosher.